# Why is redefining a command erring?

Tags: macros

I am trying to redefine `\emph` to bold its argument:

```
\renewcommand\emph[1]{{\textbf{\oldemph{#1}}}}
```

However, after typing this command before `begin{document}`, I get an error every time I use `\emph{Some text.}`: Undefined control sequence.

What is a control sequence? How do I fix my redefinition?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces your error?

Comment: How did you define `\oldemph`?

Comment: @cmhughes's answer solves my problem and has a working example. Sorry, I will make sure to provide an MWE in the future.

Comment: @DavidFaux glad it helped- my code is an example of a complete MWE :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand\emph[1]{{\bfseries{\oldemph{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\emph{hello world}
\end{document}
```